# Xamarin Forms InputTransparent doesn't work on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is my xaml. InputTransparent is set to true, but Entry still catches the input.

```
<Grid>
    <DatePicker
        Date="{Binding FundraiserEndDate}" />
    <Entry
            Text="{Binding FundraiserEndDateText}"
            TextColor="Gray"
            FontSize="13"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            InputTransparent="True" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: So when you touch `Entry`, `Grid` is not getting the touch event and invoking any assigned `TapGestureRecognizer`s that you have defined?

Comment: When I touch Entry it gets focused instead of passing an event through to DatePicker as It works on iOS

Comment: That would seem to be a bug, but not sure why in this case you want to do this, the date picker already uses an entry for the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a couple of bug reports about this, and it seems more universal than just with an Entry and DatePicker in a Grid.

See:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50992
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50362

I added the info from this question to the reports to let them know that it seems more universal than just the specific scenarios noted in the above bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same prob (InputTransparent not working issue is still actual)

I wanted to **avoid user inputs** in a custom hydrated form object w/o having to handle disabled inputs rendering (example of a switch disabled which is grey even if toogled).

For that I simply used a **grid** as example with a stackLayout on top of it so user cannot interact with all my form (entry, switches and so) :

```
grid.Children.Add(form.MainLayout);
//Trick to avoid user inputs
grid.Children.Add(new StackLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand });
scrollView.Content = grid;
Content = scrollView;
```

Comment: Nice trick. BTW, would be slightly simpler code to use BoxView rather than StackLayout, as BoxView by default fills the grid cell. `grid.Children.Add(new BoxView {});` CAVEAT - Not tested (though I have used BoxView in different circumstances to fill one or more grid cells with a color).